# Angular 2 RC-1: Dynamically add routes to component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

With the "old" new router (before rc1) I was able to add routes dynamically during runtime.

The "new" new router (post rc1) has a different api. How can I use it to add routes dynamically?

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router:Router, 
              private _appLoaderService:AppLoaderservice){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._appLoaderService.loadApps().subscribe(app => {
      let route = app.componentRoute;
      this._router. //what happens here to add the route to MyComponent?
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try createUrlTree function from router. This seems apt replacement